# Loading of d-mode fails in Emacs 24.3.50.4

Tags: emacs, elisp, cc-mode

When trying to load either `d-mode.el` or `d-mode.elc` (https://github.com/Emacs-D-Mode-Maintainers/Emacs-D-Mode) on recent snapshot of Emacs load fails as

```
Loading d-mode... [4 times]
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-typedef-decl-kwds' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-prefix-spec-kwds' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-keywords' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-regular-keywords-regexp' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-basic-matchers-before' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-matchers-2' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-typedef-decl-kwds' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-prefix-spec-kwds' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-keywords' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-regular-keywords-regexp' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-basic-matchers-before' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-matchers-2' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-typedef-decl-kwds' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-prefix-spec-kwds' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-keywords' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-regular-keywords-regexp' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-basic-matchers-before' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-matchers-2' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-typedef-decl-kwds' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-prefix-spec-kwds' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-keywords' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-regular-keywords-regexp' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-basic-matchers-before' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-matchers-2' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-typedef-decl-kwds' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-prefix-spec-kwds' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-keywords' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-regular-keywords-regexp' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-basic-matchers-before' in d-mode:
Eval error in the `c-lang-defconst' for `c-matchers-2' in d-mode:
Load error for /home/per/.emacs.d/elpa/d-mode-20130807.32/d-mode.el:
(error Recursive load /home/per/.emacs.d/elpa/d-mode-20130807.32/d-mode.elc /home/per/.emacs.d/elpa/d-mode-20130807.32/d-mode.elc /home/per/.emacs.d/elpa/d-mode-20130807.32/d-mode.elc /home/per/.emacs.d/elpa/d-mode-20130807.32/d-mode.elc /home/per/.emacs.d/elpa/d-mode-20130807.32/d-mode.elc /home/per/.emacs.d/elpa/d-mode-20130807.32/d-mode.el)
```

Comment: It's here: https://github.com/Emacs-D-Mode-Maintainers/Emacs-D-Mode